# I am not able to take video with my SD card

Tags: video, camera, sd-card

I purchased a Sandisk ultra with 64GB of memory for like 60$ but now it will not allow me to take videos. Why is this and is there any way to change it? When I display the info on the screen I can see a little REC button but it has a slash through it, implying that I cannot record (which is correct)

I did format the disk, and also when I used a friends SD card in my camera it worked for video, AND when she used my SD card in her's it worked for her to take videos(though her card is a 16GB "Silicon Power" make). We both have Nikons though mine is a D5000 and hers is a coolpix p510....

I am on a trip through Europe and I like videos because I make music videos... I would love for the expensive large memory card that I bought to work for my camera. Hence why I bought it. So if anyone has any good answers on how to get it to work, that would be much appriciated

Comment: Most likely at that price point it won't be fast enough to do video.  Sandisk do a number of cards - what exact card is it (what class and speed is it?)

Answer (score 5):

There are two possible problems, first is that your camera does not appear to have SDXC support.  32GB is the limit of the SD and SDHC file system used on lower capacity memory cards.  To move to 64GB, you have to move to exFat which your camera may not support, so the card may simply be too big.

It is also possible the card is simply too slow to support your chosen resolution and quality level.  Have you tried stepping down the quality (to IBP or less than 1080p)?  The Ultra line of SanDisk cards is one of their slowest lines and $60 for a 64GB card is not expensive, it is dirt cheap.  To give you an idea, the SanDisk Pro Extreme SD card that I use (which is still slower than my compact flash card I use) was $150 for a 64GB card that handles 1080p video at All I frame storage.

Update: After some more reading of the manual, it appears the problem is the card size.  I see your camera doesn't even support 1080p video at all and 720p should be fine on an Ultra card.  It simply doesn't support exFat, so you will need to limit yourself to a SDHC card of no more than 32GB.  It might be worth doing some more digging on that too as there are SDHC cards listed for your camera, but none in the 32GB range (but that may simply be that there weren't any available when it was made.)  I would verify 32GB compatibility before buying a 32gb card since 16GB is the biggest listed in the manual.